# Excel VBA, IF Statement failing to check if variables match

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am trying to compare a programmatic calculation to an existing total line, I declared all of the Variables as Double, however once they are set the Type is showing as "Variant/Double" and the IF statement is not seeing them as matching values.
I hope I explained this well enough! Please help :) [image: Screen Shots from Code]

EDIT: After correcting the declaration: [image]
The IF Statement is still failing

Comment: That does not define them each as a `Double` - You have to do it like this: `Public debitTotal As Double, creditTot As Double` - etc - it seems like it should, right? But it doesn't.

Comment: Regarding the edit: probably "failing" due to floating-point error. I'd `Application.Round` those to a significant number of digits before comparing.

Comment: @BigBen <3 that did it! thank you so much!

Comment: @braX Thank you too, It dose seem intuitive! :D

Answer (score 1):

It is so by design. If you want to declare all as double this is the way:

```
Public debitTot as Double, creditTot as Double, debit as Double, credit as Double
```

The way to compare `Double` (or any floating point variable) is with the `Round()` function:

`If Round(debitTot, 2) <> Round (creditTot, 2) Then`

- [Floating point arithmetics reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

Comment: Application.Round fixed the IF statement!